# I am working with fabric js and want to drop object on outside of other object's border

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I am working with fabric js and want to drop object on outside of other object's border.
Droppable object should not inside of other object.It should move on border only not inside the object.

Like this:

[image]

```
<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", {
    selection: true,
});

canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {


    var name = options.target.name;

    if (canvas.getActiveObject().get('type') == 'group') {

        var element = canvas.getActiveObject();
        var top = element.get('top');
        var left = element.get('left');
        $('#get_top').val(top);
        $('#get_left').val(left);
        $('#results').text('left: ' + left + ' ' + 'top: ' + top);
    }

    var a = $('#get_left').val();
    var b = $('#get_top').val();
    //  alert(a);

    if (name == 'hor_line') {

        options.target.left = Math.round(a);
        options.target.top = Math.round(b);

    }


});


if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == 'green_line') {
    // canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, 100, 200, 200], {top: 180, stroke: 'green', strokeWidth: 2,angle:327,lockScalingX:true,lockScalingY:true }));
    var top_val = $('#get_top').val();
    var left_val = $('#get_left').val();

    var element = canvas.getActiveObject();

    var ln = new fabric.Rect({
        left: element.get('left') + 60,
        top: element.get('top'),
        width: 200,
        height: 10,
        fill: '#ccc',
        stroke: '#000',
        // lockMovementY: true,
        angle: 0
        // bringToFront: true
    });
    // ln.name = 'hor_line';
    // canvas.add(ln);
    var dt = new fabric.IText("200", {
        left: element.get('left') + 60,
        top: element.get('top'),
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        fill: '#000000',
        fontSize: 14,
        // Scaling: false,
        // hasRotatingPoint: false,
        // transparentCorners: false,
        // selectable: false,
        cornerSize: 7,
        angle: 0
    });
    // dt.name = 'hor_name';
    // canvas.add(dt);

    var groupdoorway = new fabric.Group([ln, dt], {


        // left: element.get('left') + 600,
        // top: element.get('top'),
    });
    groupdoorway.name = 'hor_line';
    groupdoorway.angle = 0;
    canvas.add(groupdoorway);
    save();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and give us the code you have so far.